# How to start an iOS push notification from an in-app process

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I'm building an app that plugs into a third-party service that will send messages to the iOS device. So far I've been unable to find any documentation on then starting off a push notification when the delegate method is fired to say that a new message has been received.

So far, I've got the app registering to receive push notifications and the delegate method firing, I'm just not sure how to connect the two together?

The app will have a minimum deployment of iOS 5.1 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that in this case it is not push notifications that I want but local notifications instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how remote notifications work. Their main purpose is to notify application about some event. So application only receives remote notifications and note send them. So scenario is:

App is notified via

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: //if running
```

or

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: //if closed
```

According to notification payload you determine what exact action you need to perform. For example notification says that a new message was sent to the user. Then you need to send your custom request to the your server and get that new message.

Comment: so there is no way for me to 'notify the app of the event' manually from inside the app?

Comment: You need periodically send update request to your server for that.